# how do I start a simple container?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I've read the [quick start guide](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/quickstart) and I've got as far as

- I have a cluster
- I can see that I need to type a `kubectl run` command to start my container.

I want to start a publicly available docker container, which I can start on any docker-enabled machine with this command

```
docker run -d \
   -e DRONE_SERVER=wss://ci.fommil.com/ws/broker \
   -e DRONE_SECRET=<redacted> \
   -e DOCKER_MAX_PROCS=1 \
   -e DRONE_TIMEOUT=30m \
   -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
   --restart=always \
   --name=drone-agent \
   drone/drone:0.5 agent
```

what is the equivalent Google Console / cubectl command? I've got as far as

```
kubectl run agent \
  --image=drone/drone:0.5 \
  --env="DRONE_SERVER=wss://ci.fommil.com/ws/broker" \
  --env="DRONE_SECRET=<redacted>" \
  --env="DOCKER_MAX_PROCS=1" \
  --env="DRONE_TIMEOUT=30m" \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

but this `-v` line isn't quite right. I need to make sure that the `/var/run/docker.sock` is mounted in the container as the sole purpose of it is to launch sub-processes in docker to run CI jobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're right, creating volumes using the [imperative commands](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_create/) to create volumes without config files isn't available in Kubernetes.

But it's easy to write some configuration. Based on this [blog post](https://gc-taylor.com/blog/2015/10/27/example-drone-ci-kubernetes-manifests) and your requirements a "modern" config might look like.

deployment.yml:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: agent
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: agent
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: DRONE_SERVER
          value: "wss://ci.fommil.com/ws/broker"
        - name: DRONE_SECRET
          value: <redacted>
        - name: DOCKER_MAX_PROCS
          value: "1"
        - name: DRONE_TIMEOUT
          value: 30m
        image: drone/drone:0.5
        name: agent
        args: ["agent"]
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /var/run/docker.sock
            name: docker-sock
          - mountPath: /var/lib/docker
            name: docker-lib
      volumes:
        - name: docker-sock
          hostPath:
            path: /var/run/docker.sock
        - name: docker-lib
          hostPath:
            path: /var/lib/docker
```

This could now be used with `kubectl create -f deployment.yml` and stopped with `kubectl delete deployments -l app=agent`

Comment: that's great, thank you! I updated your answer with the exact yml that worked for me. The file is ridiculously repetitive, it would be good if it could be trimmed. It's like a competition to say "agent" as much as possible.

Comment: I also like to use --generator=run-pod/v1 if you want a really simple pod instead of a deployment/replicaset/...